# Alter button width to fit text width

Tags: html, css, button, width

I've got a button with some text in it, and the text is too long for the button so it's wrapping automatically to the next line. As I have a fixed button height, the second line of text in the button is hidden since overflow is not set to visible.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdVob.png)

Is there a way to set the button to change its width and make it as long as the text inside?

My current css:

```
.block .btn {
    background-color: #464646;
    color: #fff;
    border:none;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.block .btn:hover{
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 255)
}
```

EDIT:

Found my problem: there was some leftover styling for width set in the style="" property of the actual button in the HTML. There weren't any issues in the CSS itself. Thanks for the answers anyway!

Comment: `<Button>` elements automatically expand to fit the text. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/W599g/ Please post your HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 7):

Its a little hard to say exactly without more CSS or HTML provided...but this may be due to white space wrapping, try setting `white-space` to `nowrap` on the button

e.g.

```
button{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> The white-space CSS property is used to to describe how whitespace
>   inside the element is handled.

Comment: It successfully prevents it from wrapping, but the width of the button doesn't increase, so the text kinda just goes off the button and to the right now :(

Comment: Sounds like this is happening due to a restriction on the parent container. Its difficult to help without HTML/CSS but see you found your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You're fixing the `height` of the button.  Try using `min-height`instead in case the text needs more height.